# Why does my HANA XS browser session not timeout on inactivity?

Tags: hana, hana-xs

I have an XSJS page served by HANA. When I try to access it from a browser, I need to go through a basic authentication mechanism which is fine.

So far so good. But how can I configure HANA XSEngine so that it times out my web session after I have left it unused for a long time? I have configured xsengine -> httpserver -> sessiontimeout parameter to 30 (I told it is in seconds) but that does not help. So long as the browser remains open, the session remains live.

One trick I have is to close the browser. Another trick is to delete active login sessions in the browser history. Both force me to re-login, very nice. But these are so lame because they rely on a user action. I am sure SAP HANA is wiser than that.

I will greatly appreciate your help. Is there a different parameter to set? I am on SP07. I run xsengine as a separate process.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, You shouldn't be using Basic Auth at all. [Here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https) [are](http://adrianotto.com/2013/02/why-http-basic-auth-is-bad/) [some](http://swaggadocio.com/post/48223179207/why-the-hell-does-your-api-still-use-http-basic-auth) resources regarding that.

You should look at using the other methods of login. I assume you are trying to authenticate yourself as a HANA user. For this, you can use the super simple `Form` based authentication. To use this, you just have to include the following in your `.xsaccess` file at the root of the package:

```
{
    "authentication":[
        {
            "method":"Form"
        }
    ]
}
```

This would route you to a Login page that comes with HANA where you can login. Post successful login, it will redirect you back to your application.

So the flow would be something like this:

- You visit `/some/app/index.html` for which you need to be authenticated by HANA.
- You are redirected to `/sap/hana/xs/formLogin/login.html` where you will login as a HANA user
- You are redirected back to `/some/app/index.html` now authenticated as the user you logged in as.

When you use something like this, a proper session is maintained. At this point in time, your setting of `xsengine > httpserver > sessiontimeout` will work.

You can find a lot more information about this in [this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/fa/8fb4512594494e98a138ef8b2206a9/content.htm?frameset=/en/05/49991ea9984835b8c06c12123b7fe2/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/34/29fc63a1de4cd6876ea211dc86ee54/plain.htm&node_id=67&show_children=false) section SAP Hana Developer Guide.

Hope this helps. Please avoid using basic authentication.

Comment: Thanks Shrayas. Good point re form. Yes we first used form-based and then reduced level, hoping to find a clue. If I enter an xsjs url in the browser addr bar, it forces a re-login after N seconds. However if I have a webapp which was loaded with a login, and the app makes an ajax call - to the very same xsjs url - then there is no call to re-login. Since mine is an SPA, I am stuck. Any hints?

Comment: It is unbelievable to me that it is not possible to set http session timeout for each xs application. How can be possible?!